# On the solution of the Black-Scholes equation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to solve it for a European call option. Basically, I have to solve the following
\begin{align}
e^{{-r(T-t)}}{\textrm  {E}}_s
[(S_{{T}}-X){\mathbf{1}}_{{S_{{T}}>X}}]=e^{{-r(T-t)}}{\textrm  {E}}_s[S_{{T}}{\mathbf{1}}_{{S_{{T}}>X}}]-Xe^{{-r(T-t)}}\underbrace{{\textrm{E}}_s
[{\mathbf{1}}_{{S_{{T}}>X}}]}_{\Pr_s[S_{{T}}>X]}
\end{align}
where the subscript $s$ means the operator is conditioned on $S_t=s$, with $t<T$. The process $S_t$ is a geometric Brownian motion, and $X$ is a constant (the strike price).

\begin{equation}
    S_t=S_0e^{\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t}e^{\sigma W_t}\leftrightarrow W_t = \frac{\ln\frac{S_t}{S_0}-\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t)\tag{1}
\end{equation}
$\leftrightarrow$ is a bijection, so the probability can be shifted over $W_t$, but... how?
\begin{equation}
{\Pr}_s(S_T>X)=:{\Pr}(S_T>X|S_t=s)\overset{?}{=}{\Pr}\left(W_T-W_t>-{\frac {\ln{\frac {S_t}{X}}+\left(r-{\frac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{{2}}\right)(T-t)}{\sigma}}\right)
\end{equation}

I don't understand how to get to the last fraction on the right from $(1)$.

Comment: I know that for a Brownian motion $\Pr(W_T>X|W_t)=\Pr(W_T-W_t>X)$, but where is there that $X$ at the denominator, whereas $S_T$ disappeared? And why the plus sign after the natural log? Shouldn't it be a minus?

Comment: Is it correct that $\Pr(S_T>X|S_t=s)=\Pr(W_T-W_t>f^{-1}(X)-f^{-1}(s))$, where $f$ is such that $S_t=f(W_t)$?